# Change openlayers map div options dynamically

Tags: openlayers-2

I have two HTML div on my page,

```
<div id="map" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black"></div>

<div id="map2" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black"></div>
```

I want to move my map from `"map"` to `"map2"` but not working. I am using `map.setOptions` method.

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
    minResolution: "auto",
    maxResolution: "auto",
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
    ]
});


map.setOptions({
    div: "map2",
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
    minResolution: "auto",
    maxResolution: "auto",
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
    ]
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/843upac4/) is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use map.render("map2");

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/pnzunjpz/

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. But map.setOptions does nothing. I wonder why created this method?

Comment: You can use it to set or override options (for example set the displayProjection before you add a mousePositionControl) but the div-option is used in the initialize function when the map object gets created.